# Delete tags that do not contain a certain child

Tags: regex, notepad++

I got a file full of tags like this:

```
<Header>
...
<UserData>
<UserID></UserID>
...
</UserData>
...
</Header>
```

I need to clean the file deleting every `<UserData>` that doesn't contain a `<UserID>` with a specific value (say DE123 just for the sake of the example) and maintaining everything else.

For example if I have something like this:

```
<Header>
...
<UserData>
<UserID>DE123</UserID>
...
</UserData>
<UserData>
<UserID>JJ456</UserID>
...
</UserData>
...
</Header>
```

I need to make it like this:

```
<Header>
...
<UserData>
<UserID>DE123</UserID>
...
</UserData>
...
</Header>
```

How can I achieve this? Tried regex but the only thing I accomplished was inverted bookmarking EVERY line except that specific `<UserID>`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
<UserData>(?:(?!<\/UserData>|<UserID>DE123<\/UserID>)[\s\S])*<\/UserData>
```

Substitution: empty

- `<UserData>` starting with `<UserData>`
- `(?:...)*` non-capture group, with any occurrances
- `(?!<\/UserData>|<UserID>DE123<\/UserID>)[\s\S]` negative lookahead, make sure while testing a `[\s\S]`(any character including a new line), neither `<\/UserData>` nor `<UserID>DE123<\/UserID>` is consumed.
- `<\/UserData>` ends with `<\/UserData>`

When this regex matches anything, means its a complete `<UserData>...</UserData>` enclosure, with no `<UserID>DE123<\/UserID>` found inside.

You can replace `<UserID>DE123<\/UserID>` part to anything you want.

See the [proof](https://regex101.com/r/tKGDz9/1/)

Comment: thank you so much! I guess I need to study regex more :P